# How select datas between values in sql table

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I work on a SQL table with different parts delimited by easily identifiable texts. I would like to extract data between this texts of the same field

| Field1 | Field2 |
| --- | --- |
| Name1 |  |
| ... |  |
| Name2 |  |

I try this SQL query :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Field1 BETWEEN 'Name1' AND  'Name2'
```

The result shows me only the extremities but not the interior.

Could you, please, help me ?

Comment: In SQL, rows have no "order". `BETWEEN 'Name1' AND  'Name2'` means (alphabetical) between "Name1" and "Name2", so "Name123" would be a fit, not matter in which row this is stored.

Comment: @FunThomas. Thanks for your reply. Do you know an SQL query that could solve my problem?

Comment: Databases are not spreadsheets - they typically do not have a set "row order" - you select records based only on field values of the records you want to return, not on how records are arranged.  In other words, think of a table as an unordered "bucket" of records, not a "stack".

Comment: It is not clear what your problem is. If you want to return records that alphabetically fall between "Name1" AND "Name2" regardless of record order, that's what your query should output. If you want to return records 10 ("Name1") through 20 ("Name2") that is entirely different issue. Might get acceptable result if your records have a sequential numeric identifier that can be used to filter records. More realistic data sample might help.

Comment: Show us examples of 'interior' , what makes them interior?